# Alternative of Select DATE_FORMAT(date, format) in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using Apache-Spark SQL and Java to read from parquet file. The file contains a date column(`M/d/yyyy`) and I want to change that to some other format(`yyyy-dd-MM`). Something like `Select DATE_FORMAT(date, format)` that we can do in mysql.
 Is there any similar method in Apache-Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is parse the string using `to_timestamp` with your current schema and format it with the one you desire using `date_format`:

```scala
val df = Seq("1/1/2015", "02/10/2014", "4/30/2010", "03/7/2015").toDF("d")
df.select('d, date_format(to_timestamp('d, "MM/dd/yyyy"), "yyyy-dd-MM") as "new_d")
  .show
+----------+----------+
|         d|     new_d|
+----------+----------+
|  1/1/2015|2015-01-01|
|02/10/2014|2014-10-02|
| 4/30/2010|2010-30-04|
| 03/7/2015|2015-07-03|
+----------+----------+
```

Note that the parsing is pretty robust and supports single digit days and months.